# Where is the 2nd season of True detective set?

Tags: true-detective

As we know, the 1st season of True Detective was set in the state of Louisiana and the [teaser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OfU7CGY5DQ) for season 2 shows some explicit shots of a particular place (the intermingled highways). I want to know in which state of the USA True Detective season 2 is set. Is there any info available or can anyone tell by looking at the opening scene of the teaser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Season 2 will take place in California:**

> Just as the bayous and oil fields of Louisiana formed an indelible
>   part of True Detective's first season, season two will explore the 400
>   miles of California between Los Angeles and San Francisco — in
>   Pizzolatto's words, "the places that don't get much press and where
>   you wouldn't normally set a television show."

You can find more info regarding particular cities and towns [here](http://www.vulture.com/2015/02/true-detective-season-2-heres-what-we-know.html).

> Another [link](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/04/09/true-detective-season-2-teaser_n_7034444.html?ir=India) from Huffington post confirms this and adds more info
>
> Farrell will play detective Ray Velcoro, Vaughn is criminal Frank
>   Semyon, McAdams is detective Ani Bezzerides and Kitsch is war vet and
>   motorcycle highway patrol officer Paul Woodrugh.
>
> We know that **Season 2 will be based on the occult history of the
>   transportation system, tracing the murder of a corrupt city manager
>   and a high-speed railway deal that connects Northern and Southern
>   California.**

Comment: I have yet to see anything that can be called "occult" in season 2.

Comment: @Jakob I've read an article a while ago stating that the show creators decided no to include any occult elements in the second season, because they felt they didn't match the setting. We will see if it's true or not, although so far it seems it is.